# how can I maintain curves when converting from geodatabase to postgresql using og2gui

Tags: postgis, postgresql, ogr2ogr

I am using the ogr2gui to convert a feature class in a geodatabase to a postgresql feature class. My original data is in a file geodatabase, and I am using the folder OpenFileGDB format as my input type. I can see that where I previously had curves, they are now gone in the postgres feature class. How can I maintain the curves? I am running postgreSQL 9.2 with postgis 2.0.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newest ogr2gui from http://www.ogr2gui.ca/ is using GDAL 1.11. The application does not show it anywhere but you can check it from the installation directory. If you find "gdal111.dll" from there you are having GDAL 1.11 as well.

The support for curve geometries was added to GDAL 2.0 https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc49_curve_geometries. So the answer for you your question seems to be "Not with any existing ogr2gui version". Download a command line version of GDAL 2.0 from http://www.gisinternals.com/ and try if it can preserve the curves.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't follow you completely. Is there a dll for GDAL 2.0 I can download and replace the gdal111.dll with? Or I can import using GDAL via command line? How can I find the syntax for that? I'm not so familiar with this.

Comment: If you have gdal111.dll in your ogr2gui directory you know that it is using GDAL 1.11 and it is for sure too old for you. You can't update the application by flipping in gdal200.dll but the whole program must be recompiled and practically it means that you can't use ogr2gui. However, you can find GDAL 2.0 which includes ogr2ogr command line utility from gisinternals and it may be possible to do what you want with ogr2ogr. For the syntax read http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html, http://www.gdal.org/drv_openfilegdb.html, and http://www.gdal.org/drv_pg.html.

Comment: Ok I see. I checked out the link but I don't see where to download GDAL 2.0?

Comment: If you have 64-bit Windows take for example this http://www.gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1600-x64-gdal-mapserver.zip. Unzip, go to the directory where you unzipped it, run sdkshell.bat and you should have a command window. Test with `ogrinfo` It should write an error and a list of supported format on your screen.

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded and ran ogr2ogr in command line, my output still loses the curves. Maybe there is a setting I need to specify?

Comment: By reading https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc49_curve_geometries closer it looks like FileGDB driver does not belong to those which have curve geometry support. And there is indeed an open ticket https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5890 which refers to gis.stackexchange. Can you export data from FileGDB into for example GML with ESRI tools?

Comment: yes actually i am testing with a dxf I exported from the file gdb as that seems to support curves but I'm having an issue setting the srid

Comment: I was able to convert from dxf and it appears to have maintained the curves, but i can see there are some other slight changes in the geometry. Why would this be? is there a tolerance setting? I will continue to research