# Why is the geometry changing slightly when I import shapes into a postgresql database with postgis?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry, file-geodatabase

I recently posted this question when first trying to import data from a file geodatabase into a postgis database: [how can I maintain curves when converting from geodatabase to postgresql using og2gui](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163069/how-can-i-maintain-curves-when-converting-from-geodatabase-to-postgresql-using-o)

It appears that curves are not yet supported when converting from a file geodatabase, so I converted my data to dxf, then used ogr2og2 (gdal 2.0) to import into my postgres database. It appears the curves have been maintained, but now there are slight changes to the geometry, up to a few feet difference. Is there some kind of tolerance setting I can adjust? Or some way to convert without losing the curves and the geometry changing?